# Use an object declaration in parenthesis when creating a Collection

Tags: java, class, queue

The author defines a class StringLengthComparator to compare String length for items in a queue.

```
class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String value1, String value2) {
        return Integer.compare(value1.length(), value2.length());
    }
}

Queue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new StringLengthComparator());
```

With this declaration, we can sort the priority queue by string length.

Here I don't know why use "new StringLengthComparator()" when creating a queue? It seems never used or called after the declaration.

Comment: Post compilable code. You cannot have a declaration outside any class.

Comment: Try creating a PriorityQueue without specifying that comparator, see how it behaves differently.

Comment: Btw: `Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)` is a more concise way to create such a comparator.

Answer (score 2):

When you perform `new StringLengthComparator()` you are creating a new instance of `StringLengthComparator`.

This instance is then passed as argument to the constructor of `PriorityQueue` as the `Comparator` according to which its different elements are ordered. Please, see the relevant [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)).

It is equivalent to this:

```java
Comparator comparator = new StringLengthComparator();
Queue<String> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(comparator);
```

You cannot see any further references to this `Comparator` in your code, but it is used internally by `PriorityQueue`. You can verify it looking at the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/bb9d142759ece7665329b124a8ea0b16049b024a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java#L145-L177) of the class:

```java
//...

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class PriorityQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E>
    implements java.io.Serializable {

//...
  /**
   * Creates a {@code PriorityQueue} with the default initial capacity and
   * whose elements are ordered according to the specified comparator.
   *
   * @param  comparator the comparator that will be used to order this
   *         priority queue.  If {@code null}, the {@linkplain Comparable
   *         natural ordering} of the elements will be used.
   * @since 1.8
   */
  public PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
      this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, comparator);
  }


  /**
   * Creates a {@code PriorityQueue} with the specified initial capacity
   * that orders its elements according to the specified comparator.
   *
   * @param  initialCapacity the initial capacity for this priority queue
   * @param  comparator the comparator that will be used to order this
   *         priority queue.  If {@code null}, the {@linkplain Comparable
   *         natural ordering} of the elements will be used.
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code initialCapacity} is
   *         less than 1
   */
  public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity,
                        Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
      // Note: This restriction of at least one is not actually needed,
      // but continues for 1.5 compatibility
      if (initialCapacity < 1)
          throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      this.queue = new Object[initialCapacity];
      this.comparator = comparator;
  }

  //...
}
```

Comment: @MichaelHua Does the answer make sense to you? Is the concept more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) (from the oracle java docs)-

> PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
> Creates a PriorityQueue with the default initial capacity
> and whose elements are ordered according to the
> specified comparator.

The purpose of the `class StringLengthComparator implements Comparator` is to determine how the queue is ordered.